# Netgear ProSafe Switch Mounting Screw Size

Tags: hardware, rackmount

I bought a JGS524 switch from netgear and have not looked to rack mount it until recently.  The problem is, they do not list the screw size on their documentation and I would prefer not to buy a pack of cage nuts only to find out that the screws don't fit.  Does Netgear have a standard screw size? Or are the screw sizes in the U.S. predominately only one size (e.g. M6)?

I have also asked this on the Netgear community forum but thought serverfault might have an answer faster.

Thanks so much for your input!

Comment: screw is a point, but do you have the racking bracket ?

Comment: Yep, have the bracket + screws, but they don't come with cage nuts.

Comment: ok, its normal then. the cagenut depend on the cage, you should have a full bag of screw coming with the cage usually! :)

Comment: -have experienced the same, screws for attaching the rack-ears to the switch is missing. Which was it?

Answer (score 1):

The mounting hardware you use is typically independent of the hardware you are mounting. Reason being that there are different racks that have different mounting mechanisms.

If you have a square-hole rack with cage nuts, then any M6 screw and appropriate cage nut will do.

Not shipping mounting hardware is very normal. It's very rare to see any equipment ship with the actual rack mounting hardware, usually only the rack ears and/or rails themselves.